# ManyToMany field selects all model instances by default / changing default get_queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I changed my `.all` method so it would select only instances with `published=True`:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(published=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is related to the problem model fields:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    related_events = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='related')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = EventManager()
```

As a result `ManyToManyField` ends up selecting all the `Event` instances.
What would you suggest me to do in order to save the `published` functionality and be able to manually add related events? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Django does not use `Model.objects` as manager, but the `Model._basemanager`, which normally should return all objects.

You can use [**`limit_choices_to`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) here to limit the choices of the many-to-many field, like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Event(models.Model):
    related_events = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        limit_choices_to=Q(published=True)
        blank=False,
        related_name='related'
    )
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = EventManager()
```

You probably also want to remove `blank=True`, since that means that by default, you make the field not to show op in the forms. So if you want to *manually* edit the related events, then.`blank=False`.

Furthermore a `ManyToManyField` to `'self'` is by default *symmatrical*. This thus means that if `event1` is in the `related_events` of `event2`, then `event2` is in `related_events` of `event1` as well. If you do not want that, you might want to add [**`symmetrical=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

Note that there are still some scenario's where non-published events might end up in the related events. For example by adding a published event to the related events, and then "unpublish" it.

As for the manager, I think you better patch the `get_queryset` method:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(published=True)
```

Otherwise there are lot of ways to "*circumvent*" the `filter`ing. For example: `Event.objects.filter(id__gt=-1)` would still give me *all* `Event`s, but since I did not call `.all()`, this would thus not filter on published.

In the `ModelAdmin`, you could aim to specify the queryset for this `ManyToManyField` with:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_field_queryset(self, db, db_field, request):
        if db_field.name == 'event_dates':
            return db_field.remote_field.model.base_manager.all()
        else:
            super(EventAdmin, self).get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. The problem is that the all the `published=True` events ends up related to each other and I can't undo that even through admin interface. I want to add relations manually.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk: well the automatic part is, as specified, due to the `blank=True`, but it looks to me that atuomatically adding objects is probably located somewhere else. `blank=True` does *not* mean that the m2m can be empty, it can be empty by default, blank means that it is not required to be part of the form (by default).

Comment: Ok, I got the `blank=True` part. The problem with all the event relating to each other by default started when I rewrote `all` method. But I need to rewrite it to show all the published events someplace else.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk: what if you patch the `get_queryset`?

Comment: It almost works. I can't see unpublished events even in admin dashboard, and I need that so i could set `publish` to True later

Comment: So you want different behavior in the admin dashboard? Then I think you better change the `ModelAdmin` class that deals with the `Event`.

Comment: Or you can set the `queryset` in the `Form` for the users to restrict that. Point is that you should not solve the entire problem at the model level, since the model level, does not know (much) about forms, users, views, an how it is used.

Comment: This form will be only accessible in admin dashboard. I guess I need to change `ModelAdmin` somehow so it show all the events, not only published

Answer (score 1):

That's what I ended up doing in order to show only published events in my html and show all the events (published and unpublished) in admin dashboard.

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
"""
changing get_queryset() to show only published events.
if all is set to True it will show both published and unpublished
if False, which is default it will show only published ones
"""
    def get_queryset(self, all=False):
        if not all:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(published=True)
        else:
            return super().get_queryset()

class Event(models.Model):
    related_events = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='related')
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = EventManager()
```

And in ModelAdmin I call `get_queryset` with `all` set to `True`, otherwise I won't be able to see unpublished ones.

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Event.objects.get_queryset(all=True)
```

I could not simply change my model's `all` method because it would mess with my `ManyToManyField` by adding all the model instances to to it. So I did all this.